# How can i set text size in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

[Compiled application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eANrX.png)

I want to make the Hello World text bigger, but i can't figure out how

I tried using `staticText1->SetSize(32)`, `staticText1->SetSize(wxSize(32,32))` and replacing `wxDefaultSize` with `wxSize(32, 32)`, but nothing works (I am not getting errors, it just doesnt change the text size)

This is my current code:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class Frame : public wxFrame
{
    private:
        wxStaticText* staticText1 = new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, "Hello, World!", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxALIGN_CENTER);
    public:
        Frame() : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "spageta", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(400, 200)) {
            staticText1->SetForegroundColour(wxTheColourDatabase->Find("Black"));
        }
};

class App : public wxApp
{
public:
    App();
private:
    wxFrame* NewFrame = nullptr;    
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

App::App()
{

}

bool App::OnInit()
{
    NewFrame = new Frame();
    NewFrame->Show(true);
    return true;
}

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(App);
```

Comment: try following: `wxFont font = staticText1->GetFont(); font.SetSize( 32 ); staticText1->SetFont( font );` inside the constructor of wxFrame

Comment: @Igor i tried that but i got this error `error: 'class wxFont' has no member named 'SetSize'; did you mean 'SetStyle'?`

Comment: sorry, use `SetPointSize()/SetPixelSize()`. One or the other.

Comment: @Igor thanks, this worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the font size and not the window size. The best way to do it is to change the size of the same font it already uses, e.g. `window->SetFont(window->GetFont().Scale(1.5))`, which would make the font 1.5 times bigger. The same approach can be used to make it bold, or italic etc.